# Why WPF controls don't have Tag property?

Tags: wpf, controls

I think all WinForm controls have a Tag property which I found very convenient on occasions. However, this Tag property seems to be gone for WPF controls like DataGrid. Can anybody explain why? Is there a better way in WPF to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WPF controls do have a [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx)-property (Because of the base-class). However with the concept of the [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), the tag-property is not anymore very important.

Comment: You can also create an attached property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) for more complex situations.

Comment: @Bradley: +1 Right, this is a very powefull possibility and much more neat than a Tag-property!

Answer (score 0):

The `Tag` property misses meaning. You can use [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to create more semantic properties on any control.